# Date object por que muestra un dia mas?

Tags: javascript, date

se que el mes lo empieza a contar desde cero por eso sale un mes mas y debo quitarle uno. Pero porque el dia muestra uno menos?

```js
var fecha = new Date(1989, 10, 10);
 
//1989-11-09T23:00:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 2):

Depende de tu zona horaria. Al crear la fecha estás creando una fecha a 10 de noviembre de 1989 a las 00:00 en tu zona horaria.

Lo que estás mostrando es la misma fecha en formato ISO que muestra la fecha respecto al uso horario UTC.

La fecha para tu zona horaria sigue siendo en cualquier caso correcta:

```js
var fecha = new Date(1989, 10, 10);
console.log('Formato ISO:', fecha.toISOString());
console.log('Formato local:', fecha.toLocaleString());
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema lo tienes con la diferencia de horario UTC en comparación con GMT. Para que lo calcule con tu hora local puedes crear la fecha

```
 var fecha = new Date(1989, 10, 10);
var fecha= new Date(fecha.valueOf() + fecha.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
```

De esta forma si saldrá el Fri Nov 10 1989 00:00:00 GMT 0000

El 00:00:00 será la diferencia horaria que tengas según tu uso horario. Es decir que según tu uso horario te saldrá en horas minutos y segundos en vez de 00:00:00 si tu uso horario es de -05:00 entonces te saldrá:

Fri Nov 10 1989 05:00:00 GMT -0500

Answer (score 0):

Porque simplemente el constructor `Date` recibe los parámetros:

```
new Date(
    año_num,
    mes_num,
    dia_num
)
```

> Done, **año_num, mes_num, dia_num** son valores enteros con las representaciones de
>   las partes de una fecha. Como valor entero, el mes se representa de 0
>   a 11, con 0=enero y 11=diciembre.

---

**Referencia:**

- [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date)